# Check if value exists in nested array with template package

Tags: multidimensional-array, go, template-engine

Using the `text/template`, I need to find out if any object in an array has a certain property value.

Let's say I have a list of people (json):

```
[
    {"name": "ANisus", "sex":"M"},
    {"name": "Sofia", "sex":"F"},
    {"name": "Anna", "sex":"F"}
]
```

Using the template, I want to have this output:

```
Females:
Sofia
Anna
```

But the header, `Females:`, should only show in case there are actually any person with `sex` set to `F`. How can I perform this within the template system? My first attempt was by using a variable:

```
{{$hasFemale := 0}}
{{range .}}{{if eq .sex "F"}}{{$hasFemale := 1}}{{end}}{{end}}
{{if $hasFemale}}Female:{{end}}
```

I didn't get this to work because the $hasFemale within the range is in a different scope and not the same as the one initiated with 0. I can't seem to find a way to change a variable once it is initiated.

"Working" example: http://play.golang.org/p/T-Ekx7n9YQ

And I can not move this logic to the application; it must be done within the template.

Comment: This sort of logic in templates will probably become much easier when Go 1.2 drops. (http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#text_template). Maybe try tip for now? I think it already has the template comparison operators working nicely, but not sure.

Comment: Oh, that might be a way. But my company (I got my boss to accept me using Go :D) might have issues with me using tip. I also added a working example to the question for people to fiddle with.

Comment: Go 1.2 is meant to be released in December, so it may be worth starting to experiment with it now, so that by the time it releases as a stable version you're already taking advantage of the new features. Feature freeze was in September so it should be a pretty stable API from now on.

Comment: Just checked it. While Go 1.2 seems to include the eq function, I can't see that it would solve the actual problem of this question though.

Comment: Actually, upon re-reading your question, perhaps these links would be of more use. "help accessing nested structs in html/template"  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/6PR9txCkSuM and http://play.golang.org/p/jncmKgLTb6 for Kyle Lemon's example.

Comment: That is more about accessing nested values. My problem lies more in trying to send a value to the scope outside the range loop.

Comment: Then sorry, I can't see any way of doing that beyond changing the application logic (maybe with a custom template function http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs)

Comment: @ANisus What are you trying to achieve? It looks like you're on the wrong track. If your template differs greatly for these two states, use separate templates. Also, why do you want a state in the template?

Comment: @nemo In reality, I have my Go application that takes two arguments: 1) a template file and 2) a json file. It executes the template with the data and outputs the file. The output file is then passed on to wkhtmltopdf to generade a pdf. Each template/data pair have arbitrary data structures beyond my control, so the Go application must be generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would solve this differently. You generally don't want state in templates, they ought to be simple.

As you only want to know whether or not there are females in your data set, define a method `HasFemales` on your data and call it from the template. You don't necessarily need to define a struct, you can use a custom type and a definition like this ([your modified example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/vPupL5FDiD)):

```
type People []interface{}

func (p People) HasFemale() bool {
    for _, v := range p {
        if m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); !ok {
            return false
        } else if _, ok := m["sex"]; ok && m["sex"] == "F" {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Your template would then look like this:

```
{{if .HasFemale}}Female:
    {{range .}}{{if eq .sex "F"}}{{.name}}{{end}}{{end}}
{{end}}
```

This is, of course, not as type safe as a struct and not as nice as a struct so I recommend
using the `encoding/json` reflection feature to map values to a struct and define the method on that. This also has the benefit of being able to cache the result of `.HasFemale` internally so you don't need to iterate every time.

**Update regarding your comment**:

> I have my Go application that takes two arguments: 1) a template file and 2) a json file. It executes the template with the data and outputs the file. The output file is then passed on to wkhtmltopdf to generade a pdf. Each template/data pair have arbitrary data structures beyond my control, so the Go application must be generic

In this case, make `HasFemale` generic. This is similar to what you did in your question but has the benefit to abstract the nesting of the range, making it possible for you to store the result in a variable and have the state throughout your template. Example:

```
type Data []interface{}

func (p Data) HasField(name string, value interface{}) bool {
    for _, v := range p {
        if m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); !ok {
            return false
        } else if _, ok := m[name]; ok && reflect.DeepEqual(m[name], value) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Example usage:

```
{{$hasFemale := .HasField "sex" "F"}}
{{if $hasFemale}}Female:
    {{range .}}{{if eq .sex "F"}}{{.name}}{{end}}{{end}}
{{end}}`
```

Comment: I like the idea, and would use if it I could. However, my incoming data comes from a json file with arbitrary structure, so the Go application can, in my case, not be hardcoded to deal with specific data structures. Next template/data pair might have lists of products of different types instead of people.

Comment: Yes! Now you've got me thinking. While I might not be able to use the Data type because of structure complexity, I can create a template Function with the same pattern `{{if hasField . "sex" "F"}}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, however I just had a similar use case where I needed to make a column in an html table optional dependant on if a field exists anywhere within the range.

The original poster was almost there, they just had a frequent gotcha with go and was setting the variable in the wrong scope.

So instead of `{{$hasFemale := 1}}` which set the variable within the if, they should have written it as `{{$hasFemale = 1}}` then it would have worked as they originally written it.

```
{{$hasFemale := 0}}
{{range .}}{{if eq .sex "F"}}{{$hasFemale = 1}}{{end}}{{end}}
{{if $hasFemale}}Female:{{end}}
```

Here's their original example with the fix https://play.golang.org/p/m_RPJmqsuet

Comment: Correct -- but when this question was asked, the `=` syntax didn't exist. That was added in Go 1.11. https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#text/template